# how to perform a structural search and replace?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, resharper

I've got a short code snippet that exists in about a hundred projects:

```
        new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext => new OwinCommunicationListener(Startup.ConfigureApp,
            serviceContext, ServiceEventSource.Current, "ServiceEndpoint"))
```

I would like to replace this with:

```
        new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext => new OwinCommunicationListener(Startup.ConfigureApp,
            serviceContext, ServiceEventSource.Current, "ServiceEndpointHttps"))
```

Please note that the code snippet I am going to *searching for* could be in different formats:

**It could be all on one line**

```
    new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext => new OwinCommunicationListener(Startup.ConfigureApp,             serviceContext, ServiceEventSource.Current, "ServiceEndpoint"))
```

**It could be on multiple lines:**

```
        new ServiceInstanceListener
(serviceContext => 
new OwinCommunicationListener
(Startup.ConfigureApp,
            serviceContext, 
ServiceEventSource.Current, "ServiceEndpoint"))
```

**How do I perform a structural find/replace in this situation?**

Comment: Can you not replace *ServiceEndpoint* with *ServiceEndpointHttps* or do you think they occur in different places that should not be replaced?

Comment: i've created the simplest example that i could, generally there would be not just 1 change but could be multiple changes in a code block, and keep in mind that code blocks might be formatted differently